# How to validate form and post data when true with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which validates some input fields. So far so good, now I want to check if the function is "true" and if so, the data can be posted.

So far I have this:

```
<div class="input">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="some value" />
    <div class="formerror__icon"><span class="hidden">Enter name</span></div>
</div>
<div class="input">
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="some value" />
   <div class="formerror__icon"><span class="hidden">Enter email</span></div>
</div>
<div class="input">
   <input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" value="some value" />
   <div class="formerror__icon"><span class="hidden">enter phonenr</span></div>
</div>
<div class="input">
   <input type="button" class="submitContactBtn" />
</div>
```

And my JS looks like this:

```
function validateForm() {
  var nameReg = /\w+\s+\w+/;
  var numberReg = /^[0-9]+$/;
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

  var name = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#customeremail').val();
  var phonenumber = $('#customertel').val();

  if (name == "") {
    $('#name').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#name').next('.formerror__icon').show();
  }
  else if (!nameReg.test(name)) {
    $('#name').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#name').next('.formerror__icon').show();
  }

  if (email == "") {
    $('#mail').addClass('form__input--error')
    $('#email').next('.formerror__icon').show();
  }
  else if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
    $('#email').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#email').next('.formerror__icon').show();
  }

  if (phonenumber == "" || phonenumber.length > 8 || phonenumber.length < 8) {
    $('#customertel').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#customertel').next('.formerror__icon').show();
  }
  else if (!numberReg.test(phonenumber)) {
    $('#tel').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#tel').next('.formerror__icon').show();
  }
}

$('.submitContactBtn').on('click', function (e) {
  validateForm();

  // if validateForm is "true" the data must be sent - otherise re-validate!
```

The code above works fine so far, only that it tries to post no matter what, and I want to make the function true or false. How can I achieve this? or is there another way?

Comment: You can simply use the jQuery Validate plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just these forms let say that is ok to go with your idea, but if it will get bigger you should use a jquery plugin, it treats much more cases and is easier to maintain.

You can see a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/as8wkLdz/1/)

Your simplified js will look like (there are a lot of way doing this, but I kept your main code) :

```
function validateForm() {

    var nameReg = /\w+\s+\w+/;
    var numberReg = /^[0-9]+$/;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#customeremail').val();
    var phonenumber = $('#customertel').val();

    var errorClass = 'form__input--error';

    // assume that the form is valid by default
    var isValid = true;

    // clear all extra data added to fields after validation
    $('#name, #email, #customertel').removeClass(errorClass);

    if (!name.length || !nameReg.test(name)) {
       $('#name').addClass(errorClass);
       isValid = false;
    }

    if (!email.length || !emailReg.test(email)) {
       $('#email').addClass(errorClass);
       isValid = false;
    }

   if (phonenumber.length != 8 || !numberReg.test(phonenumber)) {
      $('#customertel').addClass(errorClass);
      isValid = false;
   }

   return isValid;

}

$('.submitContactBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    if (validateForm()) {
        // the form is valid - handle it here
    }

    // else is needed only if you want to handle something special if the form is not valid
    // unless the validation will be called again next time clicking the submitContactBtn
});
```

There are some extra comments which can help you.
One more stuff that I have added about css :

```
.formerror__icon {
    display: none;
}

.form__input--error + .formerror__icon {
    display: block;
}
```

Just show error messages directly from css to keep the js cleaner and easier to handle.

PS : I am not very good at regexp but I am sure that the length (not empty, 8 for phone and so on) also could be treat inside the expressions

Comment: You do not stop the submission

Answer (score 1):

You can return `true` in your validate function or in other cases `false` like:

```
function validateForm() {

  var nameReg = /\w+\s+\w+/;
  var numberReg = /^[0-9]+$/;
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

  var name = $('#name').val();
  var email = $('#customeremail').val();
  var phonenumber = $('#customertel').val();

  if (name == "") {
    $('#name').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#name').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    return false;
  } else if (!nameReg.test(name)) {
    $('#name').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#name').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    return false;
  }

  if (email == "") {
    $('#mail').addClass('form__input--error')
    $('#email').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    isValid = false;
  } else if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
    $('#email').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#email').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    return false;
  }

  if (phonenumber == "" || phonenumber.length > 8 || phonenumber.length < 8) {
    $('#customertel').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#customertel').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    return false;
  } else if (!numberReg.test(phonenumber)) {
    $('#tel').addClass('form__input--error');
    $('#tel').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
//and on submit
$('.submitContactBtn').on('click', function (e) {
    if(!validateForm()) e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: `$('#ContactForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    if(!validateForm()) e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I also suggest a form tag and to use the on submit instead of on click

Comment: @mplungjan Agree but is actual OP code don't want to change much :)

Answer (score 1):

You're reinventing the wheel, use http://jqueryvalidation.org/ and you just need to set the `type` and `required` on your `input` fields, i.e.:

Small example:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please provide your name, email address (won't be published) and a comment</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="cname">Name (required, at least 2 characters)</label>
      <input id="cname" name="name" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="cemail">E-Mail (required)</label>
      <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
      <input id="curl" type="url" name="url">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="ccomment">Your comment (required)</label>
      <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script>
$("#commentForm").validate();
</script>
```

---

Read the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/) for advanced usage.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to use external plugin... sorry for not mentioning

Answer (score 0):

Use an `onclick` in your HTML

```
<input type="button" class="submitContactBtn" onclick="return validateForm();" />
```

Remove the `on` event in your js and let `validateForm();` return true or false like so:

```
function validateForm() {

     var nameReg = /\w+\s+\w+/;
     var numberReg = /^[0-9]+$/;
     var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
     var ok = true;

    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#customeremail').val();
    var phonenumber = $('#customertel').val();

    if (name == "") {
      ok = false;
       $('#name').addClass('form__input--error');
       $('#name').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    }
    else if (!nameReg.test(name)) {
      ok = false;
       $('#name').addClass('form__input--error');
       $('#name').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    }

    if (email == "") {
      ok = false;
       $('#mail').addClass('form__input--error')
       $('#email').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    }
    else if (!emailReg.test(email)) {
      ok = false;
       $('#email').addClass('form__input--error');
       $('#email').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    }

   if (phonenumber == "" || phonenumber.length > 8 || phonenumber.length < 8) {
      ok = false;
      $('#customertel').addClass('form__input--error');
      $('#customertel').next('.formerror__icon').show();
   }
   else if (!numberReg.test(phonenumber)) {
      ok = false;
      $('#tel').addClass('form__input--error');
      $('#tel').next('.formerror__icon').show();
    }

return ok;


}
```

Comment: You should not suggest inline onclick - especially not when there is jQuery available